# Google scripts: Copy a full column from one tab, and overwrite column in another tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, columnsorting

I'm attempting to create a "simple" investment calculator for a game. So I have one tab with a market API that updates every 30 mins with the current price of all items on the market (Tab name: Prices), and posts it to another tab (MaxPrices) in a new column for each update. Currently, the script I have is

```
function readSalesNum() {
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prices");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MaxPrice");

// Copy from 2nd row, 5th column, all rows for one column 
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(2, 5, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
var itemnames = sheetFrom.getRange(2, 1, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

//Paste to another sheet from first cell onwards
sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);

//My attempt to make it overwrite itself
sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getFirstColumn(),itemnames.length,1).setValues(itemnames);

}
```

This posts the updated market prices from the Prices tab into the MaxPrices tab for every item, in a new column every X amount of time I set in Triggers.

What I need now is a script that will take a column from the Prices tab, post it into the MaxPrices tab, and overwrite itself each update rather than posting it into a new column each time.

Image of the script and what happens/ what I want to happen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh3rn.jpg

Comment: Can you add a screenshot as to what your current result it? I'm kinda lost as to what you're exactly asking

Comment: [Spreadsheet setup](https://imgur.com/a/bZ4xt4z) I would like Column A from the Prices tab to be posted into Column A in the MaxPrices tab, and each time the trigger runs, it will just overwrite instead of posting into a new column

Comment: Just fix the column name cannot solve it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @KinSiang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I spotted a small mistake in your attempt.

I believe `getFirstColumn()` returns an int that's the first *empty* column, which in this case make you append data instead of overwriting it.

Try this:

```js
sheetTo.getRange(1,1,itemnames.length,1).setValues(itemnames);
sheetTo.getRange(1,2,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
```